# Why my prettier doesn't work in react project on save?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, prettier, formatter

**Expected result:**

Applied prettier - code formatter in my react project on save.

For example, I hope the semicolon can be automatically added when I save the file.

[add semicolon automatically when save](https://i.stack.imgur.com/veEpN.png)

**My Problem:**

Based on Vscode Output, It seems that prettier has been applied already.
However, the semicolon were not added automatically.

[Vscode output about prettier](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZoim.png)

**Dependencies:**
prettier: ^1.18.2 / Vscode: 1.73.1 (Universal) / Mac OS

**What I have tried:**
After searching lots of suggestions online, I have checked these things in VScode.

[select default formatter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8sMHt.png)

[enable formatting on save & paste](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IVqEX.png)

[enable prettier](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GTLHi.png)

[set resolveGlobalModules to false](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OYrk3.png)

```
Setting in my .prettierrc:

{
    "useTabs": false,
    "singleQuote": true,
    "trailingComma": "all",
    "printWidth": 80,
    "arrowParens": "avoid",
    "bracketSpacing": true,
    "quoteProps": "as-needed",
    "semi": true,
    "tabWidth": 2,
    "jsxBracketSameLine": false,
    "jsxSingleQuote": false
}
```

Any suggestion would help! Thanks a lot.

Comment: did you configure the default formatter in vs-code?

Comment: @Xiduzo Yes, I have set my default formatter as 'prettier-code formatter' in vs-code.